# what are the basic steps to start any game applications in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am not familiar with gaming application, So Now I want to start a simple kids game application which displays the score with limited time.

What are step to proceed. Do I need to register with game center, I don't know about this. Please give  me any suggestions that would help to start game application.

Thnak you,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to register an iPhone developer program, you won't be able to test your code on a device without it. Alternatively, you could purchase a copy of Xcode and develop on a simulator until you are ready for actual device. In any case, you will need the $99 program for publishing.

Now, you will need to learn Objective C. Grab yourself a book and understand how views work before designing your game.

Comment: I have done many applications but not gaming applications, I know objective-c. To test the application in the device do I need to get any thing from apple.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to run on a device (or to publish to the app store), you will need an iOS developer account for $99.  However, if you want to just test you device in the built in simulator on your computer, you can do it for free.

Next, figure out what kind of game you want to make.  Plan what is going to happen, what views are necessary, design an interface, write some code.  Thats the basic process.

You DO NOT need to regester with Game Center.  Game Center provides some easy to use feature for your app, such as simple to implement online leaderboard.  If you want to use them (you will need the $99 account, not the free account), set up Game Center.  I don't want to write a tutorial here since thats off topic.

Game creation is just like any other app creation.  I hope this helps.  You said above in a comment you are familar with Objective-C so start programming the game as you would any other app.

Comment: Thanks dude, So first, I will develop a game application and test it in the simulator later I register it with device i will proceed. How can I test it in the simulator for free

Comment: Do I need to register in simulator with existed apple Id which I used to submit apps in app store or I need to create new one. When submission time I will use older one.

Comment: You shouldn't need a new one.  Your old one is fine, and you dont need any for the simulator.